# Compare and bookmark + lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Compare plugin returns +/- lines.  What is the regex to select all + lines form the compared document for later copying these bookmarks?  alternatively, how to copy/select only + lines to paste it in new document OR how to get only non-recurring results from the compared document directly?

Photo at - https://prnt.sc/qkprzi

Comment: Have you checked the patch command in command line, it might gives you the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel - conditional formatting/compare, filter and paste the sorted/highlighted cells.

For > 1M lines, use MS Access and its query wizard.